# How to count role attributes from html page in python

Tags: python, html, selenium

is it possible to count how much time specific role shows up? There is a website and I want to use python to do this.

e.g

```
<div class="container">
 <div role="grid">
  <div role="gridcell"></div>
  <div role="gridcell"></div>
  <div role="gridcell"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to count how much time "gridcell" shows up. I'm newbie so I don't know if this is possible if not can I just count how much "divs" are in `<div role="grid">`

I don't have much code to show just something basic

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import keyboard

def show():
    if(keyboard.read_key() == "c"):
      #print(count_gridcell)
    
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get('https://www.example.com')

time.sleep(5)
show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the DOM you have provided in the query:

If you want to count the `role='gridcell'` attributes:

```
gridcells = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@role='gridcell']")
print(len(gridcells))
```

If you wan to count the `role` that contains any role attribute that as `grid` in it (in this case - `grid` and `gridcell`:

```
grids = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@role, 'grid')]")
print(len(grids))
```

If you want to count all the role attributes:

```
role_attrs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@role]")
print(len(role_attrs))
```

Snapshots:

[gridcell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuRJ9.png)

[any role containing grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te8z1.png)

[role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tOxP.png)

Comment: I'm getting some error, it's long so I uploaded it here for you to check if you know what's happening [link](https://imgur.com/a/5e5GgRd)

Comment: The error is `NoSuchWindowException: Window was aleady closed`. I think this does not relate to locator, but the window in which the locator exists is closed perhaps. Per the DOM, the locators works. Updated snapshots in the answer for reference

Comment: I am afraid, if you still get the issue, share the wesbite link to inspect, if it is ok to do so.

Comment: Ok I fixed it, it was my fault. Now it's working!